# Change Image on arrow click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am working on setting up images that can be clicked through with arrows. Currently I have the images all showing up via a loop and an array. I have been able to set it up so that when you hover on a *smallimage* preview the main image will change to that image. Aka you can hover on them to see the larger version.

I am attempting to do the same with arrows on the side of the photo but am coming up short. How would I change my code to allow the images to be changed with arrows?

Thanks for any help!

//Showing the images

```
             <% var imgsrc = awspath + listings.currentimages[0] %>
            <img  id='mainPicture' class="image-resposive" src=<%=imgsrc%>>

                <div id='allimages'>
                 <% for(var i = 0; i < listings.currentimages.length; i++ ) { %>
                  <div class='smallerImages'>
                     <% var imgsrc = awspath + listings.currentimages[i] %>
                  <img class="small" src="<%= imgsrc %>">

                </div>
                <% } %>
                </div>
```

//Setting up hover to make larger...

```
  $('.small').hover(function() {
   $('.small').removeClass('selectedImage')
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   $(this).addClass('selectedImage')
   $('#mainPicture').attr('src', src);
   });
```

Comment: What you mean by `through with arrows`?

Comment: Press a right/left arrow to go to the next image in the array.

Comment: Do you mean by the keyboard arrows?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @BraianMellor I did but I'd be very curious to see how it would work by clicking an arrow on screen. Any advice? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery `keydown` event over the document element. Just a quick demo:

```js
function selectImage(img) {
  $(".small").removeClass("selectedImage");
  var src = $(img).attr("src");
  $(img).addClass("selectedImage");
  $("#mainPicture").attr("src", src);
}

$(".small").hover(function() {
  selectImage(this);
});
   
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        // left
        case 37: 
          var prev = $(".selectedImage").prev(".small");
          if(!prev.length) {
           prev = $("#allimages").find(".small:last-child");
          }
          selectImage(prev);
        break;
        // right
        case 39: 
          var next = $(".selectedImage").next(".small");
          if(!next.length) {
           next = $("#allimages").find(".small:first-child");
          }
          selectImage(next);
        break;
        default: return;
    }
    // Prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

```css
.small {
  border: solid 2px transparent;
}

.selectedImage {
  border: solid 2px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="mainPicture">
<br>
<div id="allimages">
  <img class="small" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
  <img class="small" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/f00/fff">
  <img class="small" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/f0f/fff">
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to also make this work with clickable arrows? Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: and what you mean by "clickable"?

Comment: Meaning arrows you'd click on-screen. Figured it out on this post. Thanks again for the help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164468/show-next-image-in-array-onclick